# struts2 Error while retrieving generic property class for property=parameters

Tags: exception, struts2

I am getting the below exception. Any input on why is occurs would be helpful

`DEBUG [http-8081-1] (CommonsLogger.java:72) - Error while retrieving generic property class for property=parameters
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer.getClass(DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer.java:314)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer.getKeyClass(DefaultObjectTypeDeterminer.java:93)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.accessor.XWorkMapPropertyAccessor.getProperty(XWorkMapPropertyAccessor.java:93)
 at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:2230)
 at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:114)
 at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
 at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
 at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:141)
 at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:212)
 at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:258)
 at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:494)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:217)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.getValue(OgnlValueStack.java:342)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValue(OgnlValueStack.java:331)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.tryFindValueWhenExpressionIsNotNull(OgnlValueStack.java:307)
 at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ognl.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:293)
 at org.apache.struts2.components.Property.start(Property.java:162)
 at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.tags.CallbackWriter.onStart(CallbackWriter.java:73)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:296)
 at freemarker.core.UnifiedCall.accept(UnifiedCall.java:130)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
 at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
 at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
 at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
 at freemarker.core.IfBlock.accept(IfBlock.java:82)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
 at freemarker.core.MixedContent.accept(MixedContent.java:92)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.visit(Environment.java:210)
 at freemarker.core.Environment.process(Environment.java:190)
 at freemarker.template.Template.process(Template.java:237)
 at org.apache.struts2.components.template.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.renderTemplate(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:157)
 at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.mergeTemplate(UIBean.java:559)
 at org.apache.struts2.components.ClosingUIBean.start(ClosingUIBean.java:59)
 at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:53)
 at org.apache.jsp.pages.THDPaymentMethod_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fsubmit_005f1(THDPaymentMethod_jsp.java:6665)
 at org.apache.jsp.pages.THDPaymentMethod_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(THDPaymentMethod_jsp.java:2363)
 at org.apache.jsp.pages.THDPaymentMethod_jsp._jspService(THDPaymentMethod_jsp.java:347)
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
 at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)`

Comment: thank you.. i always tried to click the UP/DOWN arrows and got a message about Voting.. never really tried to click on the checkbox.. now i know

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me when I use a submit taglib of type image.
Moreover, I downloaded the struts2 samples 2.2.1

I added  to the struts2-showcase-2.2.1/conversion/enterPersonsInfo.jsp form and it generates the error previously describe.

Could you tell me if it's reproducable on your side with the struts2-showcase sample?

Tested with struts2.2.1 on Jonas4.10.3

Answer (score -1):

You obviously have a NullPointer because you didn't set the parameters property. Maybe you just forgot to make this property public, but all help we can give you if you just post a stacktrace is reading out the message to you.